# Custom targets for widget Layout Updates in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I would like help working out how to add a custom container as a 'Layout Update' for a widget..

Currently, I only have the 3 basic options to choose from (Main Content Area, Siderbar Main and Sidebar Additional), but I would like to be able to add widgets to containers that I've created through various default.xml files.

How would I go about doing that?

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In widget.xml You create additional area.Under catalog module you can see that.

```
<widget id="new_products" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" is_email_compatible="true"
        placeholder_image="Magento_Catalog::images/product_widget_new.png" ttl="86400">
    <label translate="true">Catalog New Products List</label>
    <description translate="true">List of Products that are set as New</description>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="display_type" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Display Type</label>
            <description translate="true">All products - recently added products, New products - products marked as new</description>
            <options>
                <option name="default" value="all_products" selected="true">
                    <label translate="true">All products</label>
                </option>
                <option name="item" value="new_products">
                    <label translate="true">New products</label>
                </option>
            </options>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="show_pager" xsi:type="select" visible="true"
                   source_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno">
            <label translate="true">Display Page Control</label>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="products_per_page" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Number of Products per Page</label>
            <depends>
                <parameter name="show_pager" value="1" />
            </depends>
            <value>5</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="products_count" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Number of Products to Display</label>
            <value>10</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Template</label>
            <options>
                <option name="default" value="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml" selected="true">
                    <label translate="true">New Products Grid Template</label>
                </option>
                <option name="list" value="product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml">
                    <label translate="true">New Products List Template</label>
                </option>
                <option name="list_default"
                        value="product/widget/new/column/new_default_list.phtml">
                    <label translate="true">New Products Images and Names Template</label>
                </option>
                <option name="list_names"
                        value="product/widget/new/column/new_names_list.phtml">
                    <label translate="true">New Products Names Only Template</label>
                </option>
                <option name="list_images"
                        value="product/widget/new/column/new_images_list.phtml">
                    <label translate="true">New Products Images Only Template</label>
                </option>
            </options>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Cache Lifetime (Seconds)</label>
            <description translate="true">86400 by default, if not set. To refresh instantly, clear the Blocks HTML Output cache.</description>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
    <containers>
        <container name="sidebar.main">
            <template name="default" value="list_default" />
            <template name="names_only" value="list_names" />
            <template name="images_only" value="list_images" />
        </container>
        <container name="content">
            <template name="grid" value="default" />
            <template name="list" value="list" />
        </container>
        <container name="sidebar.additional">
            <template name="default" value="list_default" />
            <template name="names_only" value="list_names" />
            <template name="images_only" value="list_images" />
        </container>
    </containers>
</widget>
```

Please go through the `<containers>` tag above code you will understand.There is a container tag

Comment: Thanks for your reply shine. I guess I should have mentioned that I have been trying to add extra containers to the `module-reports/etc/widget.xml` file, as I'm trying to add the Recently Viewed widget to a new container, but they haven't been appearing in the CMS..

Comment: Its working for me. Add recently viewed widget  to homepage after that view a product then check your home page.

Comment: You should include custom container on the page layout

Comment: Thanks mate, the problem was the custom container that I had set up hadn't been iven a label attribute, so Magento was ignoring it as a possible layout destination.
I now have to figure out how to add my <container> node to the <containers> node for the recently viewed widget without editing the core files...